# CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set in qtcreator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

<s>Is there a way (like command line argument or some function in CMakeLists.txt) to print all command line arguments supplied to cmake invocation? Equivalent of bash "echo $@"</s>

I need this to debug, why cmake invoked from qtcreator does not find my compiler (msvc12). After inspecting qtcreator sources, I see that it appends some environment by cmake arguments depending on selected kit. I got messages like

> CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set

, when I select both "Nmake Desktop Qt MSVC2013 ..." or "Ninja Qt MSVC2013".

When I call cmake from command line, it finds compiler with no additional parameters:

> -- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works

Comment: Have a look at CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log and CMakeFiles/CMakeOutpu.log, there you can find details for test output.

Comment: CMakeFiles folder was not created, only cache file. Then I installed ninja by "choco install ninja" and after qtcreator reboot, both ninja and nmake works. No idea why Nmake generator did not work before.

Comment: If your problem is solved, close the question. If the solution would help other people, answer yourself and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was solved by installing ninja. I thought that the problem was not finding compiler by cmake invoked by qtcreator:

> CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set

After installing ninja and restarting qtcreator, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading Visual Studio 2017.

For some reason, when ADDING (?) `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in the cmake configuration in Build & Run to the location of the Visual Studio compiler, it should work:

- Key: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
- Value: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe` ==> replace version with the correct one

Don't forget to click "Apply Configuration Changes" below.
Very strange though, because after building, the cmake run becomes `CMake Project was parsed successfully.`and believe-it-or-not, the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is gone!